# Redirecting files and changing url using htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-analytics

Used to working on the front end of sites, though I've strayed into serverside territory, so wondered if there was an answer to this question.

I have website split in two, half on a server I have access to, half on a third party server to which I have no access. I am however required to use Google analytics to track these pages. Access to pages on this remote server is limited to providing a header and footer snippet of html. So my idea is to include an iframe in either the header or footer. The included file (catchall.php) then reads the  info about the parent document, then requests a specific document url from the server I have access to including the title information - www.myserver.com/specificfolder/title off parent document

All well and good up to this point (apart from if an end user has js switched off).

Using htaccess and php I'd like redirect the URL to a specific file in the requested folder, I added this to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specificfolder/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myserver.com/specificfolder/google.php
```

which sort of worked, but I loose the "correct title" bit, so the php file (google.php) can't read the original full url
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

The intended end result was the correct title is placed into the google.php  tag and the google analytics package then reads the url requested + page title, thus giving me a means of tracking the pages on the remote 3rd party server.

Thanks for reading this far, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you miss to show `RewriteRule` line in your .htaccess?

Comment: "Limited to providing a header and footer snippet" - it's not quite clear why you don't  embed the GA code in one of those snippets.

Comment: I was under the impression the GA tracking code was only valid when placed in documents residing on my own server (own domain), not pages under a different domain. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Eike - Thanks for the heads up, got the GA linked up in the html snippets without all the other faff.

Comment: If you expect traffic between those domain you should look into cross domain tracking (this can be easily set up in the javascript tracking code), else a user who changes the domain will be counted double.